# scrapy single spider to pass multiple item classes to pipeline

Tags: scrapy

I am new to scrapy. In items.py, I declare 2 ItemClass called ItemClass1 and ItemClass2. A spider method parseUrl get the html and scrape data and put into lists for respective Item Classes.

```
e.g:
C1Items = []
C1Item = ItemClass1()
#scrape data
C1Items.append(C1Item)
...
C2Items = []
C2Item = ItemClass2()
#scrape data
C2Items.append(C2Item)
...
```

finally: C1Items and C2Items contain required data.

```
return C1Items #will pass ItemClass1 data to pipeline
return C2Items #will pass ItemClass2 data to pipeline
```

Could you please advise what is the best way to pass both C1Items, C2Items to pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either combine all the items of different classes into one list and return that list, or use `yield` statement:

```
C1Item = ItemClass1()
#scrape data
yield C1Item
...
C2Item = ItemClass2()
#scrape data
yield C2Item
```

Answer (score 2):

Just combine the arrays into one big array and return that:

```
return C1Items + C2Items
```

or alternatively you could turn `parseUrl` into a generator function with:

```
yield C1Items
yield C2Items
```

Comment: Hi, I tried yield but encountered error:ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list'