# scrapy multiple item classes with extract method inside them

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, rdfa

Just to state: I am not an experienced programmer,don't be mad at me …
I am exploring scrapy possibilities (I have some Python programming skills).

Scrapping a website: lets imagine that we can have some informations extracted from *opengraph(og:)* like **'title', 'url' and 'description'**, and other informations from *schema.org*, like **'author'**, and last we want **'title', 'url', 'description' and 'date'** that can be extracted from "normal" XPath from the HTML just if there is not available from *opengraph(og:) and schema.org*.

I create 3 item classes **OpengraphItem(Item), SchemaItem(Item) and MyItem(Item)**, in separated .py files.
Inside each class there would be an extract function to extract the fields, like this example:

```
class OpengraphItem(Item):
      title = Field()
      url = Field()
      description = Field()

      def extract(self, hxs):
            self.title = hxs.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
            self.url = hxs.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()
            self.description = hxs.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
```

Then in the *spider code*, the extract function will be called like this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    my_item = MyItem()
    item_opengraph = OpengraphItem()
    item_opengraph.extract(hxs)

     item_schema = SchemaItem()
     item_schema.extract(hxs)

      my_item['date']= hxs.xpath('/html/body//*/div[@class="reviewDate"]/span/time[@class="dtreviewed"]/@content').extract()

      my_item['title'] = item_opengraph.get('title', None)
      my_item['url'] = item_opengraph.get('url', None)
      my_item['description'] = item_opengraph.get('description', None)

      if my_item['url'] == None:
            my_item['url'] = response.url

      if my_item['title'] == None:
            my_item['title'] = hxs.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()

      if my_item['description'] == None:
            my_item['description'] = hxs.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content').extract()

      return my_item
```

Does this make any sense?
It is rigth to have the created extract method inside items class?

I took a look into this other questions:
[scrapy crawler to pass multiple item classes to pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098827/scrapy-crawler-to-pass-multiple-item-classes-to-pipeline) - and I dunno if it is correct to have only one items.py with multiple and different classes inside it.

[Scrapy item extraction scope issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832368/scrapy-item-extraction-scope-issue) and [scrapy single spider to pass multiple item classes to pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069236/scrapy-single-spider-to-pass-multiple-item-classes-to-pipeline) - should I have an Itempipeline? I am not familiar with those, but in scrapy documentation says its uses and I think it not fit this problem. And Item loaders?

I ommited some parts of the code.

Comment: Yes. You can put classes in different files, or in the same file. If they're in different files, just make sure you `import` them properly.

Comment: It seems you're asking a lot of things in your question. Perhaps it would be more clear if you made different questions, one for each specific doubt or problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is rigth to have the created extract method inside items class?

That's very unusual. I can't say it's "not right", as the code will still work, but usually all the code related to page structure (such as selectors) stays in the Spider.

Item loaders might be useful for what you're trying to do, you should definitely give it a try.

Another thing, attribute assignment to item fields like

```
  def extract(self, hxs):
        self.title = hxs [...]
```

will not work. Scrapy Items are like dicts, you should instead assign to e.g. `self['title']`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried

def extract(self, hxs):
        self.['title'] = hxs [...] 

but it gives an error: "#exceptions.AttributeError: Use item['title'] = [...] to set field value ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: self['title'] without the "."